# Does declaring a structure initializes it?

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

When I declare a structure instance is it initialized or do I have to make a constructor?

How much will the constructor affect the performance since I need an array of 1000 structures?

The structure I need is very simple and it contains 4 integers. I need them to be initialized to 0.

This is my code:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    MyStruct() : a(0), b(0), c(0), d(0) {}
};

int main() {
    MyStruct array[1000];
}
```

Comment: If you take away the constructor (and thus make it implicit) you can do `MyStruct array[1000]()` which will zero-initialize all the integers.

Comment: @0x499602D2 `declaration of 'array' as array of functions` Are you sure that's correct syntax?

Comment: @user2079303 Right, my mistake. It should be `MyStruct array[1000]{}` (which only works >=C++11)

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a variable in `main`, but only as a side-effect of defining it.

And all objects are default-initialized, unless you ask for something else.

Still, that's not quite as much as you might thing. A default-initialized basic type, which is neither in static nor in thread-local storage, is still indeterminate after that.

But never fear, your type has a user-defined default-ctor, so default-initialization means that is called.
And as that value-initializes all members, everything is initialized.

If it was an aggregate, this would zero-initialize it:

```
MyStruct array[1000] = {};
```

Regarding performance, there's nothing to be done but measuring, and asking the compiler to optimize it. Keep in mind that the fastest code is code that isn't there.

Comment: Or just `MyStruct array[1000]{};` to conserve the limited supply of characters.